# How do I find the author in a List containing who has written most books in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables writer and blog. Writer table have id and name column. Blog table have id,blog and writer_id.I have to find writer who writes more blog.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The question is in the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample schema based on your very brief description, and provide an answer based on that schema.

```
create table writer(id int,name text);
create table blog(id int,writer_id int,blog text);

insert into writer values
  (1,'Writer A'), (2,'Writer B'), (3,'Writer C'), (4,'Writer D'),
  (5,'Writer E'), (6,'Writer F'), (7,'Writer G');

insert into blog values
  (1,1,'Blog 1'), (2,1,'Blog 2'), (3,3,'Blog 3'), (4,3,'Blog 4'),
  (5,2,'Blog 5'), (6,3,'Blog 6'), (7,3,'Blog 7'), (8,6,'Blog 8'),
  (9,4,'Blog 9');

select w.name,count(b.id) no_of_books
  from writer w join blog b on w.id = b.writer_id
  group by w.id
  order by no_of_books desc
  limit 1;
```

By changing the `limit` part you can change from top 1 to top 2 or 3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code. 
I hope this is helpful

```
select 
   a.name, Max(b.highest)
from writer as a
left join(
  select 
     count(*)as highest,
     writer_id 
  from blog
  GROUP BY writer_id
) as b on a.id = b.writer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be severals writers having written the same amount of books. So we'd need a limit clause that allows for ties.

**Standard SQL query:**

```
select *
from writer
where id in
(
  select writer_id
  from blog
  group by writer_id
  order by count(*) desc
  fetch first rows with ties
);
```

MySQL's `LIMIT` doesn't allow for ties, though. One could achieve the same with ranking the writers by their book count. MySQL doesn't feature ranking functions such as `RANK`, though.

So with MySQL you are forced to find another approach:

1. count books per author
2. determine the maximum count of these
3. select authors and their book count again
4. only keep authors whose book count matches the maximum book count
5. select the authors' names

**MySQL query:**

```
select *
from writer
where id in
(
  select writer_id
  from blog
  group by writer_id
  having count(*) =
  (
    select count(*)
    from blog
    group by writer_id
    order by count(*) desc
    limit 1
  )
);
```