# Having + Max function not working as expected

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, group-by

So, I was trying to show all writers with most books written using having and I tried this:

```
select *
from writer as a,(
SELECT writer_id,count(writer_id) as posts
FROM blog
GROUP BY writer_id
) as b WHERE a.id = b.writer_id 
GROUP BY writer_id
HAVING posts>=max(posts);
```

But when I execute it, it returns the whole table rather than only those with most books. Why isn't having working here? I think I am missing something. If I replace max(posts) with the actual number of max posts from my example table it works.

I am using the example tables from this question: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918977/how-do-i-find-the-author-in-a-list-containing-who-has-written-most-books-in-mysq)

Comment: Side notes: **(1)** You shouldn't use comma-separated joins anymore. They have been made redundant in standard SQL in 1992. **(2)** If you want to count records use `COUNT(*)`. `COUNT(<expression>)` is used to count non-null ocurrences. With `count(writer_id)` it looks as if `writer_id` could be null and you wanted omit such rows from counting.

Comment: The issue with your query is: To each writer you join their number of blogs. Then you group by writer, which does nothing really, as you already have one row per writer. Then you compare the writer's number of blogs with the writer's maximum number of blogs. You are taking the maximum of a number, which is just the number itself. For a writer with ten blogs you say: return this row if 10 = 10. For a writer with five blogs you say: return this row if 5 = 5. You are returning all rows.

Answer (score 1):

To get the writer with most books, you can just `order by` and `limit`:

```
select w.name, count(*) no_of_books
from writer w 
join blog b on w.id = b.writer_id
group by w.id
order by no_of_books desc
limit 1
```

If there are top ties (ie several writers with the most books) and you want to get them all, a solution is to filter with a `having` clause:

```
select w.name, count(*) no_of_books
from writer w 
join blog b on w.id = b.writer_id
group by w.id
having count(*) = (
    select count(*) from blog group by writer_id order by count(*) desc limit 1
)
order by w.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `rank()` window function:

```
select w.*, t.counter 
from writer w inner join (
  select writer_id, count(*) counter,
    rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rn
  from blog
  group by writer_id      
) t on t.writer_id = w.id
where t.rn = 1
```

This code returns also ties if they exist.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kVNTBCNWExx6Pd2Mfh9CFf/1).
Results:

```
| id  | name     | counter |
| --- | -------- | ------- |
| 3   | Writer C | 4       |
```